# Zookeeper restart always falls when restarting

Tags: apache-zookeeper, mesos, marathon

I have a 3 node master setup for marathon and mesos masters, everything is fine until I reboot one of the nodes or try restarting zookeeper.

The issue is somehow correlating to the internal DB zookeeper is using, when I delete /var/lib/zookeeper/version2/* then zookeeper comes up fine and re syncs with the other nodes.

I am using the current marathon mesos packages with zookeeper from the mesosphere repo on rhel7.

Does anybody know how to fix this? The Filesystem below does not change anything, I tried with xfs and ext4.

Another question would be to somehow backup the marathon apps - if I reboot let's say all nodes in the quorum with deleting the zookeeper DB everything is lost.

Comment: How about if you try and give [DC/OS](https://dcos.io) a chance? Then you don't need to worry about these low-level issues and can focus on actually using it.

Comment: Hi Michael, you're right but for the moment I'd like to stay with marathon/ mesos :)

Comment: Can you provide ZK logs and version?